# When enqueing a stylesheet, is it possible to remove the type attribute?

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style

I'm updating my self-built theme to HTML5, and easily made a number of changes already.

My theme's sole stylesheet is added to the page head via `wp_enqueue_style` in the `functions.php` file, as follows:

```
function gridded_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), null, 'all');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gridded_enqueue_styles');
```

The resulting markup is:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='style-css'  href='http://grantpalin.com.dev:81/wp-content/themes/gridded/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

The stylesheet is loaded, the page renders, all good. However, the HTML5 spec indicates that the `type` attribute is no longer needed for the `link`, `style`, and `script` elements.

Looking through the [codex reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style), I don't see a way to alter or remove the `type` attribute. Can this even be done?

The obvious workaround is to hard-code the stylesheet reference in my `header.php`, but that's avoiding the benefit of the enqueue functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For modify this output you can use that filter:

```
function wpse51581_hide_type($src) {
    return str_replace("type='text/css'", '', $src);
}
add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'wpse51581_hide_type');
```

You can see this hook into `wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php`

Comment: Thank you. That worked nicely. On a parallel tack, do you know if there is any way to do the same for script tags? There appears to be no `script_loader_tag` hook available, but there is `script_loader_src`, which I also tried to use, but produced no effect.

Comment: @GrantPalin I looked in the source code, `script_loader_tag` filter does not exist. Unfortunately, the entire string is hardcoded [link](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php#L124)

Comment: Is there much of a performance hit by using `str_replace` or `preg_replace` to strip the type attributes out?

Comment: Not very much, see this [replacement methods comparison](http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=175031.0). However, I would suggest using `str_replace` for better readability and slightly better performance. But `preg_replace` could be prefered provided you want to remove both " and ' -quoted attributes, e.g. `preg_replace('/\s+type=["\']text\/css["\']/', '', $src)`, and don't want to run `str_replace` twice.

Answer (score 3):

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'html5_style_tag' );

function html5_style_tag( $tag ) {
    return preg_replace( '~\s+type=["\'][^"\']++["\']~i', '', $tag );
}
```